# Act on hash change when not using routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where I'm not using the route provider but I still want to act on the hash being changed. A normal window.onhashchange in the controller works when I'm updating the URL manually but not for links:

```
<a href="#/something">Link</a>
```

The URL is updated but the event is not triggered. I'm thinking that Angular hijacks clicks on these kind of links to be used in the route provider.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: If you are using angularjs it would be much easier to use `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (locationChangeObj, path) {});`

Comment: Where is the `$rootScope`?  Can anyone share some sample code of how to initialize this?  All the examples I've looked at does not have such root scope. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I manage to find this [link](https://uiadventures.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/routechange-angularjs/) and I tried it and it works great.  I'm not sure if that's the way to do it, but it may help others as it helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try listening for [`$locationChangeSuccess`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#events_$locationChangeSuccess) in your `$rootScope`. Also, try it without the `#` in your `href`, angular should handle that internally (although that I'm not that sure about if you're not using routes).

Comment: If not using routes, it does not automatically handle it.